# How can I add additional properties to an entity in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I am using NestJS to build an api, and everything is working great so far!

I have a `users` table and a corresponding `users.entity.ts` file:

```
@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({
    unique: true,
  })
  email: string;
...
```

I am using AWS Cognito as an authentication provider - everything is working great there too. I am trying not to duplicate things, so I'd like to keep `given_name` and `family_name` values with Cognito and not have redundant fields on my postgres table.

I can get the user without problems, but I'm not sure how to "combine" them into my `user` entity.

For example,

```
// users.service.ts

const user = await this.usersRepository.findOne({
      where: {
        id: userId,
      },
    });


// id: dbc92...
// email: example@email.com

const cognitoUser = await this.cognitoService.adminGetUser(user.id);

// id: dbc92...
// email: example@email.com
// given_name: "Tony"
// family_name: "Stark"

return user;
```

I don't have a `given_name` property on my `user` entity—I'm not sure if I *need* one?

Ideally, I think what I'm trying to do is something like,

```
user.givenName = cognitoUser.given_name
user.familyName = cognitoUser.family_name
...

return user
```

But since my `user.entity` file doesn't have a `givenName` property, it's not to happy to do that.

I know I can "merge" the two objects using a spread operator, but I'd like to return the actual `user` entity if possible. How can I pull from two sources and return the proper entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mohammad said, if what you are trying to accomplish is:

```js
user.givenName = cognitoUser.given_name
user.familyName = cognitoUser.family_name
```

then you can do this:

```js
@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({
    unique: true,
  })
  email: string;
  
  given_name: string;
  family_name: string;
}
```

and be able to handle the data just from `User` but without replicating data in the database with unnecessary columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your desired properties without adding `@Column` decorator. It will not make column in your table but still you have them in your entity.

Answer (score 0):

From the official docs: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md#afterload

> You can define a method with any name in entity and mark it with @AfterLoad and TypeORM will call it each time the entity is loaded using QueryBuilder or repository/manager find methods.

### TypeORM Entity with custom properties / virtual fields:

```js
// tested with `typeorm@0.3.7` 
@Entity()
export class Post {
  @AfterLoad()
  updateCounters() {
    if (this.likesCount === undefined) this.likesCount = 0
  }
}
```

I don't think the chosen answer is quite correct because an exception for missing columns is thrown when an insert or update operation is attempted:

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/cdabaa30287d357c0ae994209e573f97f92dad22/src/metadata/EntityMetadata.ts#L806-L814

If you are interested in reading more about the issue, is sounds like a feature `selectAndMap` is soon coming to typeorm to support this in a way that is more intuitive  https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1822#issuecomment-376069476